# What is JCE Code Signing CA?

Tags: java, applet, certificate, jce

I have an applet which is signed by the following certificate chain:

```
Softkey-Kazakhstan (JCE Code Signing CA) 
    Subject: CN=Softkey-Kazakhstan,OU=Java Software Code Signing,O=Sun Microsystems Inc
    Issuer: CN=JCE Code Signing CA,OU=Java Software Code Signing,O=Sun Microsystems Inc,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US

JCE Code Signing CA (JCE Code Signing CA)
    Subject: CN=JCE Code Signing CA,OU=Java Software Code Signing,O=Sun Microsystems Inc,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
    Issuer: CN=JCE Code Signing CA,OU=Java Software Code Signing,O=Sun Microsystems Inc,L=Palo Alto,ST=CA,C=US
```

This applet contains custom cryptoprovider implementation and some additional helper jars. It must be able to work with local files and USB-devices.

Java complains that it doesn't know this certificate. Root certificate seems to be legitimate certificate from Sun used for code signing and java should know it, but it doesn't for some reason.

What should I do, so java won't complain about this applet? Should I extract this root certificate JCE Code Signing CA and install it into $JRE/lib/security/cacerts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good question. This certificate is selfsigned and not officialy in Java tursted CA (cacerts). I've found that cryptographic extensions works even if that certificate is expired (doesn't work without signing). So I suppose that JCE requires cryptoproviders to be signed with "JCE Code Signing CA" but doesn't care about validity of that certificate (maybe it is checked internally by JCE without cacerts). I also understand that it is not the case here. The problem is with javaws (JNLP distribution) which requires jars to be signed with trusted chain. Also it is stressed by Oracle about JCE Code Signing certs that **"the certificate will not work for deployment purposes"** (see: [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/getcodesigningcertificate-361306.html)). But what if it have to exist in distribution? As I said: good question.

EDIT:
Conclusions:
1. Cryptoproviders have to be signed with "JCE Code Signing CA" not necessary valid.
2. If you distribute jar signed with "JCE Code Signing CA" then certificate has to be valid. JCE sign is not enough to distribute but if exists it has to be valid.